# Null Values MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

What is the best way to handle NULL values in a search form.  I want to allow the user to search by 8 different criteria however if they leave a box blank I would like it to return all non null values for that column.  I am able to assign a default value if the field is left blank but how can I change accountant to "IS NOT NULL"? Thank you for your time.

```
    if ($specialty_name == null){
        $specialty_name = 'Accountant';
    }
```

The SQL looks like this...
WHERE `specialty_name` = 'Accountant'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if ($specialty_name == null) {
    $where = "WHERE specialty_name IS NOT NULL";
} else {
    $where = "WHERE specialty_name = '$specialty_name'";
}
```